# deinit cannot call the function

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer

i want use the deinit release a `NSTimer`,but it cant work.  i want to know how to use the `deinit`

codes:

```
class timerView: NSObject {
    var timer:NSTimer?
    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.timer = NSTimer(fireDate: NSDate(), interval: 1, target: self, selector: "timers", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop().addTimer(self.timer!, forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)
    }
    deinit{
        self.timer = nil
    }

    func timers() -> Void {
        print("true")
    }
}

    var timeV:timerView?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.timeV = timerView()
        self.timeV = nil
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate what you mean. What are you asking?

Comment: `deinit` won't get called unless you first invalidate the timer. This is because when running, the timer keeps a strong reference to its target (your `timerView` instance) and the run-loop keeps a strong reference to the timer.

Comment: @Cenny i said i want release the NStimer

Comment: @originaluser2   What should I do?,I'm so sorry.

Comment: @jianxing798 Invalidate the timer, as the answer below suggests. This will break the strong reference from the timer and therefore your instance can be deallocated.

Comment: @originaluser2  you mean a running out of the runloop,will call the `deinit`

Comment: @jianxing798 I mean that when you invalidate the timer, it will break its strong reference to your instance, and the run-loop will break its strong reference to the timer. If there are no other strong references left to your instance, then yes `deinit` will then be called and then it will be deallocated. Although by that point setting `timer` to `nil` will be pointless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just invalidate the timer:

```
timer.invalidate()
```

From [NSTimer Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/index.html):

> ... Invalidating the timer immediately
>   disables it so that it no longer affects the run loop. The run loop
>   then removes the timer (and the strong reference it had to the timer),
>   either just before the invalidate method returns or at some later
>   point. Once invalidated, timer objects cannot be reused.

Which is exactly what you are trying to do when calling dinit.

**Since the answer is not satisfactory, I can try and guess your issue: you created the timer in a class, but maybe tried to invalidate the timer from different spot in your program. But is dosen't work becuase:

> you should always call the invalidate method from the same thread on which the timer was installed.

A possible solution to such situation will be to hold the timer in it's own `struct`:

```
struct programTimer {
  static var timer: NSTimer = NSTimer()
 }
```

Comment: You are right.but you did not answer my question.

Comment: @jianxing798 You actually didn't ask a question – you just said "*i want use the deinit release a NSTimer,but it cant work.*" Without a specific question, it's hard to know exactly what you're asking. I would kindly recommend you have a read of ["How do I ask a good question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @originaluser2 ok,I'm sorry,i want to know how to use the deinit.

Comment: @jianxing798 I hope the answer is clear now. But if not, please **edit** your question, and maybe somebody will answer. Notice that the question doesn't make much sense, so I can only guess what is the problem and why would you like to call `dinit`